# Where is the best place to put modules that extend your active record models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Just a quick question that strangely I can't find anywhere (maybe I'm wording the question wrong when I ask google)...  I have some shared functionality across a few models, but not shared in any way that I'd want to make an actual class to extend, just small utility methods that I'd like to mix in.  Where is the "best practice" place to put these kinds of modules?

I can put them in `./lib`, but that feel wrong for some reason, I'm not sure.  Where's the typical place to put this stuff?

**Edit:**  I see why ./lib felt wrong now.  I didn't realize that in rails 3 it no longer autoloads ./lib by default, so I though this had moved elsewhere.  Which I guess it has in the sense that it's now up to you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We try to "name" these kinds of things and put them somewhere as appropriate. For example, "concern" is a common name for mixins that provide a specific functionality as a module mixin, so we put them in `app/concerns`. (In fact, I believe this is a default folder in Rails 4). You may need to adjust your autoload path appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

`./lib` is an appropriate place. You could namespace these similar modules together, under say, `./lib/active_record_mixins/`

Answer (score 1):

There is no "best" place, at least as you describe your mixin.

It was *always* up to you; you can add whatever you want to your list of autoloads.

I don't see why lib doesn't "feel right", it's as good as any other. Some types of mixins have names, like "concerns" and "decorators", but it's not clear if what you're mixing in falls into that broad a category.

Autoloading of everything under `lib` was turned off to control autoloading, not because it wasn't an okay place to put libraries. For modules that don't fit into a broad, app-wide category (think "decorators" or "concerns") `lib` seems perfectly reasonable.

Autoloading means you have to use `require` instead of everything being loaded everywhere; this isn't necessarily a Bad Thing, IMO.

Because it depends entirely on the nature of the code, the structure of your app, and how you *want* to structure your app, I'm not convinced there's an open-ended "best" practice.

Comment: I mean in terms of "best practice".  Like how ./app/models is the "best" place to put models (though you can hack it up such that they can actually go anywhere.)  I'm asking for this because this code will get handed off and I didn't want it to be difficult to find the mixins because I put them in some non-standard place.  

And ./lib felt wrong because it wasn't autoloading, and I noticed that there's nothing but rake tasks in there, which made me think that rails had decided this is no longer a good place to put app code.

Comment: @MasonCloud Updated answer. Nutshell: the "best" practice depends on what you're actually doing, and how you want to present it. There's no one place to put libraries.

Comment: I assume embedding libraries in HERE docs in .erb files is *probably* not a best practice...  :)  You know what I mean by "best practice", right?  If not, I meant "what is what most people do and works well".  I know there are all sorts of possibilities, and that different situations call for different solutions, but that wasn't what I was asking, sorry if that was in confusion.  I was asking, "as a rule of thumb, where do they often go?"  Anyways, I got answers that worked for me, thanks!

Comment: @MasonCloud They often go in lib, or in appropriately-named sub-directories in lib or apps. As a rule of thumb they go in those places.